# Is there a way to iterate over the second element of a std::map?

Tags: c++

I want to create a `std::vector<char>` with something like:  `v(map.begin(), map.end());` rather than iterating over all elements of the map and resizing `v` over and over.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include<vector>

int main() {
        std::map<int, char> map{{1,'a'},{2,'b'},{3,'c'}, {4,'d'}};
        std::vector<char> v;
        for(auto& [ i , c ] : map){
            // std::cout << i << " -> " << c <<"\n";
            v.push_back(c);
        }
}
```

Comment: Why not simply [`reserve()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve), if you don't want to resize?

Comment: `std::transform(map.begin(), map.end(), std::back_inserter(v), [](auto const& pr){ return pr.second; });`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C++20, you could create a view over the values by using [`std::views::values`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/values_view):

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <ranges>

int main() {
    std::map<int, char> map{{1, 'a'}, {2, 'b'}, {3, 'c'}, {4, 'd'}};    
    auto view = std::views::values(map);
    std::vector<char> v(view.begin(), view.end());
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bhxsTz6h9)

A more general purpose view is the [`std::views::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/transform_view) where you supply the transformation to be done via a functor:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <ranges>

int main() {
    std::map<int, char> map{{1, 'a'}, {2, 'b'}, {3, 'c'}, {4, 'd'}};    
    auto view = map | std::views::transform([](auto&& p){ return p.second; });
    std::vector<char> v(view.begin(), view.end());
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/TnGM9ds7b)

Comment: God, I wish I could use `C++20` at work...

Comment: @WBuck just surreptitiously add it to your build system. Who's gonna know? Just a little flag...

Comment: `std::views::values` would be even cleaner.

Comment: @cigien Oh, yes. Thanks! I'm just taking my first babysteps with ranges and missed that - but I added that to the answer now.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `reserve` on the `std::vector` in order to allocate the memory you need up front and avoid the resizing.

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main( )
{
    std::map<int, char> map{{1,'a'},{2,'b'},{3,'c'}, {4,'d'}};
    std::vector<char> v{ };
    v.reserve( map.size( ) );

    std::for_each( std::begin( map ), std::end( map ), 
        [ &v ]( const auto& pair ){ v.push_back( pair.second ); } );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, you can `reserve` space for your vector to avoid re-allocations. With the tools C++'s for loops now have for destructing things like maps, this is very clean.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include<vector>

int main() {
    std::map<int, char> map{{1,'a'},{2,'b'},{3,'c'}, {4,'d'}};
    std::vector<char> v;
    
    v.reserve(map.size());
 
    for (auto& [i, c] : map) v.push_back(c);
    for (auto& i : v) std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```